# React Props doesnt show info properly in the confirmation page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-props, setstate

I'm designing a form in React that has a main form builder **(Create Job.js)** and some form pages **(AdditionalInfo.js)** and **(Confirmation.js)**. this form had a tag input that allows you to choose tags from a drop-down list provided by an API. the selected items need to be shown later in the confirmation page.

This is my main form builder that has props and functions:**(CreateJob.js)**

```
state = {
    step:1,
    Title:'',
    requirements:'',
    Location:'',
    Benefits:'',
    Company:'',
    InternalCode:'',
    Details:'',
    Tags:[],
    Address:'',
    Department:'',
    Salary:''
  }
handleDropDown = input => value => {
  this.setState({ [input]: value }); 
}
  render () {
    const { step } = this.state
    const {Title,Benefits,Company,InternalCode,Detailss,Tags,Address,Department,Salary,requirements,Location } = this.state;
    const values ={Title,Benefits,Company,InternalCode,Detailss,Tags,Address,Department,Salary,requirements,Location}


    return (
      <div>
....
           <AdditionalInfo
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                handleChangeRaw={this.handleChangeRaw}
                handleDropDown={this.handleDropDown}
                values={values}
                />
           <Confirmation
                nextStep={this.nextStep}
                prevStep={this.prevStep}
                values={values}
                />
....
```

and this is my form page which includes the list from API and the drop down using react-select(AdditionalInfo.js):

```
export class AdditionalInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    locations:[],
    departments: [],
    tagsList:[],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('/api/jobs/list-tags',{headers:headers}).then(respo =>{
      console.log(respo.data)
      this.setState({
        tagsList:respo.data.map(Tags=>({label: Tags.name, value: Tags.id}))
      })
      console.log(this.state.tagsList)
    })
  }
render() {
  const {values, handleDropDown} = this.props

 <Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Tags 'onChange={handleDropDown('Tags')} defaultValue={values.Tags} required isMulti options={this.state.tagsList}/>
...
```

this is the list of tags received from the API:

```
Object { label: "MongoDB", value: 1 }
​
Object { label: "JavaScript", value: 2 }
​
Object { label: "HTML", value: 3 }
​
Object { label: "CSS", value: 4 }
...
```

And this is my Confirmation page which needs to show the info received from previous pages **(Confirmation.js)**

```
.....
render () {
    const {
      values: {
        Title, Benefits,
        Company, InternalCode, Detailss, Department,Tags, Salary,requirements,Location
      }} = this.props
<Row> Tags: {Tags.join(", ")}</Row>
....
```

the problem is that, instead of showing tags on the page like putting the labels next to each other 
:JavaScript,
MongoDB,
... it shows this
: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]. sorry for the long code but Im a beginner in JavaScript and I dont know how to handle it so it shows the labels. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing great, and you have done right, just simple tweak you need.
If `React` show anything like `[Object Object]` it means you are trying to render `Javascript Object` not a single value because you have got `Tags` from `props` which is an `Array of objects`.

Use it like this, it will work like butter -

```
import React from 'react';

const Confirmation = () => {
  const tags = [ // which you got from props
    { label: "MongoDB", value: 1 },
    { label: "JavaScript", value: 2 },
    { label: "HTML", value: 3 },
    { label: "CSS", value: 4 }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {tags.map(tag => tag.label).join(', ')} {/* map over tags to get the array of tag labels */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Confirmation;
```